# Javascript function to focus() on next form element not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Aaargh. I've written a simple HTML page with a form on it to take in a phone number. I put in a Javascript function that makes the focus jump to the next form box once it's full. Everything seems perfect.

However, for some reason it is not working. I can't see why since I've created a nearly identical file with only the form and the function and it works! So something in this particular file is blocking it but after 30 minutes of tinkering I can't figure out what.

```
<html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function moveToNext(curr, next) {
                    if(curr.value.length == curr.getAttribute("maxlength"))
                        next.focus();
                }
            </script>
            <title> Enter Phone Number </title>
            <style type="text/css">
                #content {
                    background:url(images/content-bg-rpt.gif) repeat;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    height: 300px;
                    width: 500px;
                }
                #formArea {

                    margin-top: 50px;
                    width: 250px;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;
                }
                #submit {
                    position: relative;
                }
                .formInput { /* These are the input styles used in forms */
                    background: #f7f7f7 url(../img/input.gif) repeat-x;
                    border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
                    margin-bottom: 6px;
                    color: #5f6c70;
                    font-size: 16px;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    padding-top: 11px;
                    padding-bottom: 11px;
                    padding-left: 11px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="content">
                    <div id="formArea">
                        <form name="enterPhone" id="enterPhone" action="phoneresult.php" method="GET">
                            <input onkeyup="moveToNext(this, document.enterPhone.d345.formInput))" type="text" class="formInput" maxlength="3" size="3" name="d012" id="d012"></input>
                            <input onkeyup="moveToNext(this, document.enterPhone.d345))" type="text" name="d345" class="formInput" maxlength="3" size="3"  id="d345"></input>
                            <input type="text" class="formInput" maxlength="4" size="4" name="d6789"></input>
                            <input id="submit" value="Enter" type="submit"></input>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Could you make a minimalist example in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. For each opening parenthesis, you need exactly one closing parenthesis. The `onkeyup` attribute of your inputs has two closing parentheses and one opening one.
2. Pass the HTML element directly, not `.formInput`.

This solves both issues for me:

```
<input onkeyup="moveToNext(this, document.enterPhone.d345)" type="text" class="formInput" maxlength="3" size="3" name="d012" id="d012"></input>
<input onkeyup="moveToNext(this, document.enterPhone.d6789)" type="text" name="d345" class="formInput" maxlength="3" size="3"  id="d345"></input>
```

Comment: Where is there a parentheses missing?

Comment: in the `onkeyup` attributes of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your code with this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vTde7/1)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="formArea">
            <form name="enterPhone" id="enterPhone" action="phoneresult.php" method="GET">
                <input onkeyup="moveToNext(this, document.getElementsByName('d345'))" type="text" class="formInput" maxlength="3" size="3" name="d012" id="d012"></input>
                <input onkeyup="moveToNext(this, document.getElementsByName('d6789'))" type="text" name="d345" class="formInput" maxlength="3" size="3" id="d345"></input>
                <input type="text" class="formInput" maxlength="4" size="4" name="d6789"></input>
                <input id="submit" value="Enter" type="submit"></input>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function moveToNext(curr, next) {
    if (curr.value.length == parseInt(curr.getAttribute("maxlength"), 10)) next[0].focus();
}
```

In your JS you were making a comparison between an integer and a string (`curr.value.length == curr.getAttribute("maxlength")`). In your HTML you weren't selecting the element properly with `document.enterPhone.d345.formInput`.

Comment: The int/string mismatch doesn't really matter since he's using `==`.

Comment: @ZachRattner exactly Zach, thanks. I was trying to figure out what j08691 meant

Comment: True it's not necessary, although it won't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving this a shot:

**JS**

```
function moveToNext(curr, next) {
    if (curr.value.length >= curr.maxLength) {
        document.getElementById(next).focus();
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="enterPhone" id="enterPhone" action="phoneresult.php" method="GET">
    <input onkeyup="moveToNext(this, 'd345')" type="text" class="formInput" maxlength="3" size="3" name="d012" id="d012"/>
    <input onkeyup="moveToNext(this, 'd6789')" type="text" name="d345" class="formInput" maxlength="3" size="3" id="d345"/>
    <input type="text" class="formInput" maxlength="4" size="4" name="d6789" id="d6789"/>
    <input id="submit" value="Enter" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JZxPR/

Answer (score 0):

try this, replace three input tags with the code below:

```
<input onkeyup="moveToNext(this, document.enterPhone.d345)" type="text" class="formInput" maxlength="3" size="3" name="d012" id="d012"></input>
<input onkeyup="moveToNext(this, document.enterPhone.d6789)" type="text" name="d345" class="formInput" maxlength="3" size="3"  id="d345"></input>
<input type="text" class="formInput" maxlength="4" size="4" name="d6789" id="d6789"></input>
```